# How to pull the "en0" from this: 'networksetup -listallhardwareports'

Tags: bash, shell

when I run this: `networksetup -listallhardwareports` I get this (MACs removed):

```
Hardware Port: USB 10/100/1000 LAN
Device: en18
Ethernet Address: 

Hardware Port: Wi-Fi
Device: en0
Ethernet Address: 

Hardware Port: Bluetooth PAN
Device: en8
Ethernet Address: 

Hardware Port: Thunderbolt 1
Device: en3
Ethernet Address: 

Hardware Port: Thunderbolt 2
Device: en1
Ethernet Address: 

Hardware Port: Thunderbolt 3
Device: en4
Ethernet Address: 

Hardware Port: Thunderbolt 4
Device: en2
Ethernet Address: 

Hardware Port: Thunderbolt Bridge
Device: bridge0
Ethernet Address: 

VLAN Configurations
```

I'm looking to pull the Device ID and only Device ID from the Wi-Fi NIC, IE: en0

I know this can be done with a little grepping, sedding and awking.  That is what I was hoping I could get some assistance with.

Thanks in advance,

Dev

Comment: Kindly always show us your expected output in CODE TAGS as well as your efforts too in your posts.

Answer (score 0):

Though not that clear, could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
your_command | awk '/Hardware Port: Wi-Fi/{getline;print "Device id: "$2}'
```

Comment: Thanks....the output from this 

networksetup -listallhardwareports | awk '/Hardware Port: Wi-Fi/{getline;print "Device id: "$2}'

Is:

Device id: en0

Answer (score 0):

This appears to do it:

```
networksetup -listallhardwareports | awk '/Wi-Fi|AirPort/{getline; print $NF}'
```